# syntax highlight group for command line on normal mode?

Tags: colorscheme

I'm trying to write my own color scheme. I use `:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim` to identify vim's syntax names.

Mostly this is working great, but I can't find the identifier for the command line in normal mode (ie, the bottom line on the terminal). That is,  while

```
hi LineNr ctermfg=black
```

makes the line numbers black, I'm not sure what the identifier is for the command line. What is the right highlight group? Is there a better place than `hitest.vim` to identify syntax groups?